# Atom on my computer doesn't seem to read \r\n\r\n correctly

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, newline

On my laptop atom colorcodes r\n\r\n correctly but on my computer it doesn't. When I write the atom program on my laptop it works but it gives me 404 error on my computer. Below is a snippet of the code.

```
import socket

mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysocket.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/page1.htm HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()


mysocket.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = mysocket.recv(512)
    if len(data)<1:
        break
    print(data.decode())

mysocket.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is using an extra `"\"`. So where you see \r or \n you should put `\\r` and `\\n`

`\` is an operator. so when you have put `\n`, python understands it as "make a  new line": `new line`.

When you have put `\r`, python understands it as "go to start of line": `Carriage Return`

To make it clear you want the actual text of `\n` you need an extra `\`

Comment: Its actually a carriage return and new line part of the HTTP protocol. It should return a page but it is not.

Comment: I figured it was because I was using my work computer and it has some security settings that prevented that code from running